# Referring to a range based on variables in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a cell to a sum of a few cells.

The cells that will be summed are variable, and based on other things (and will change on each iteration of the macro).

I coded such that I will know the row that the cells are on, as well as the column of the beginning cell and the column of the ending cell (ie. perhaps A600 to A606 will be summed). However, I have set these column and row assignments to variables, say Y, Xstart, and Xend. How do I have the sum select these ranges, of the cells which are purely defined by variables?

This was my initial guess.

```
set rng = "=SUM(& Y & Xstart &, & Y & Xend &)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use set when setting a reference to an object.  `Range.Formaula` take a string argument and so does "=Sum()".

```
Sub Example()

    Dim Xstart As Long, Xend As Long
    Dim TargetRange As Range, SumRange As Range
    Dim Y as string
    Y = "B"

    Xstart = 2
    Xend = 100

   Set SumRange = Range(" & Y &  & Xstart & ":" & Y & Xend)
   Set TargetRange = Range("A1")

   TargetRange.Formula = "=SUM(" & SumRange.Address & ")"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is Y is a variable though? Not referring the column.

Comment: I updated my answer making Y a variable.  The main thing that we're building a string to pass into the target range's formula property.  Thanks for the check mark!

Comment: This will not compile for me, the colon is highlighted and the message "Compile Error: Exped: list separator or )" appears. for the "Set SumRange = ..." line. Any ideas?